# Exclude a folder in Xenforo

Tags: .htaccess, xenforo

I have installed Xenforo in my public_html in my Cpanel which means my forum is available in **site.com**

Now I want to add another folder contains my web app and want to access it in **site.com/myapp**. I created a folder "myapp" in public_htmll beside Xenforo files and now when I enter the URL site.com/myapp it goes to a 404 page of the forum. I need to Xenforo exclude this folder and let the app lunch in this address. How can I do that?

Comment: Which web server are you using? I'm assuming Apache based on the .htaccess tag?

Answer (score 2):

You should move your XenForo installation to a subdirectory - many people use `site.com/community` as the forum root and either have a separate home page at `site.com/` or just redirect the domain root to the `/community` URL.

This then allows you to have other apps running in other subdirectories like `site.com/myapp` without issue.

Answer (score 1):

In XenForo 2.x this works fine, If you have enabled full Seo friendly urls from admin panel, Make sure you have proper .htaccess file in place. In you case, I believe you did not upload .htaccess file in public_html folder